# MongoDB Cluster Setup

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to setup a 3 node MongoDB cluster.

1) Started mongodb in all 3 nodes with the below config file.

```
 net:
       bindIp: 0.0.0.0
       port: 10901
    setParameter:
       enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
    systemLog:
       destination: file
       path: "<LOG_PATH>"
       logAppend: true

processManagement:
   fork: true
storage:
   dbPath: "<DB_PATH>/data"
   journal:
      enabled: true
security:
   keyFile : "<KEY_FILE_PATH>"
    sharding:
      clusterRole: "configsvr"
    replication:
      replSetName: "configReplSet"
```

2) Created Admin user in one of the config node and able to login with the admin user.

```
mongo --port 10901 -u "admin" -p "adminpwd" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --host <IP>
```

now the console says,  user:PRIMARY>

3) Created replica set using the below command.

```
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "configReplSet",
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "<IP1>:10901" },
      { _id : 1, host : "<IP2>:10901" },
      { _id : 2, host : "<IP3>:10901" }
    ]
  }
)
```

4) Executed rs.status() and got the proper output.

5) Started Mongo shards with the below config in all 3 instances.

```
net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 10903
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "<LOG_PATH>"
   logAppend: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
storage:
   dbPath: "<DB_PATH>/shard_data/"
   journal:
      enabled: true
security:
   keyFile : "<KEY_FILE>"
sharding:
  clusterRole: "shardsvr"
replication:
  replSetName: "shardReplSet"
```

6) Created Admin user in one of the shard node also and able to login with the admin user.

```
mongo --port 10903 -u "admin" -p "adminpwd" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --host <IP>
```

7) Created shard replica set using the below command.

```
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "shardReplSet",
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "<IP1>:10903" },
      { _id : 1, host : "<IP2>:10903" },
      { _id : 2, host : "<IP3>:10903" }
    ]
  }
)
```

8) Started the router with the below config

```
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: <LOG_PATH_FOR_MONGOS>

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 10902

security:
  keyFile: <KEY_FILE>

processManagement:
  fork: true

sharding:
  configDB: configReplSet/<IP1>:10901,<IP2>:10901,<IP3>:10901
```

6) Connected to mongos using mongo

```
mongo --port 10902 -u "admin" -p "adminpwd" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --host <IP>
```

Now, I see the below in my command.

```
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
mongos>
```

7) Now added each shard in the mongos interface.

Since, I have configured replica set,

sh.addShard("shardReplSet/:10903, :10903, :10903")

**Issues :-**

1) Unable to connect to mongodb from the remote machine

I am able to connect to the other node within these 3 nodes.

From Node1,

mongo --port 10902 -u "user" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --host

mongo --port 10902 -u "user" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --host

mongo --port 10902 -u "user" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --host

All the above 3 connections are working from Node1 and Node2 and Node3.

But If I try from my localhost to connect to these instances, i get timeout error.

I am able to ssh to these servers.

2) I am running config on port 10901, shard on port 10903 and router on port 10902. Running, config, shard and router on each node. Is this ok?

DB path for config and shard are different. Have to create admin user on each service(config, shard, router). Is this correct?

Created replica set for config and shard server, but not for router? Is this ok?

4) Unable to connect to these instances from a remote mongo chef tool. I use the router port to connect to these instances? Is this correct? If so, Do I need to run router on each node?

5) Do we need to connect to the port 10903 or 10902 or 10901 to create new databases, create new users for db's.?

6) Is there anything else important to be added here?

Thanks

Comment: are the required ports open from the server you're trying to connect?

Comment: Port was not opened. It works now.